# Number of Inverse Pairs Modulo Prime $p$

Tags: prime-numbers, finite-fields

Is there a result which gives a lower bound on the number of inverse pairs $(a, a^{-1})$ modulo prime $p$ lying in the interval $[1,t]$, where $t < p$?

Comment: The expected number of such pairs is about $t^2/p$.
That the actual number is $t^2/p + O(p^{1/2} \log^2 p)$
follows from the upper bound $2 p^{1/2}$ on the size of a
Kloosterman sum.  In particular there's a nontrivial lower bound
for $t \gg p^{3/4} \log p$. $$ $$
This bound (also for length-$t$ intervals mod $p$ other than $[1,t]$)
appears as a Lemma in Merel's proof that for each $d$ there's an
(explicit though large) upper bound on the size of the torsion group
of an elliptic curve over any number field of degree $d$.
